# Node.js / Socket.io Chat App Works Fine ... Until Real Traffic Causes A TypeError?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm (trying) to run a chat app on Heroku.  I'm a front-end guy trying to build out my back-end skills, so I was aware this was going to be a bit of stretch for me, but I tested the app out locally before deploying it Heroku.  Once it was deployed to Heroku,  I asked several friends to log on & off and help me kick the tires.  It worked fine.  Fast forward to tonight, when the time time for the app to handle actual traffic from strangers (as part of a holiday marathon) and ... it crashed.  Almost immediately.

**Here's the Heroku error log**:

```
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
[web.1]: /app/server.js:44
[web.1]:     io.to(user.room).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, msg));
[web.1]:                ^
[web.1]: 
[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'room' of undefined
[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:44:16)
[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
[web.1]:     at Socket.onevent (/app/node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.js:253:20)
[web.1]:     at Socket._onpacket (/app/node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.js:216:22)
[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/socket.io/dist/client.js:205:28
[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Ok, I get that there's some undefined wonkiness going on here - although, with my limited Node/JS skills I'm hard-pressed to quickly zero in on the source - but wouldn't this error cause the app to simple not work at all, rather than initially work then crash as soon as it encountered any real traffic?

I'd like to get this app in robust working order, so I'd be greatly appreciative if someone with better JS chops than mine could help me out here.

**Here's  my server.js file**:

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const formatMessage = require('./utils/messages');
const { userJoin, getCurrentUser, userLeave, getRoomUsers } = require('./utils/users');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'web_apps--listener_chat')));

const botName = ' Jon Solobot '; 

// Run when a client connects
io.on('connection', socket => {
   socket.on('joinRoom', ({ username, room }) => {        
       const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room);
    
       socket.join(user.room);

    // Welcome current user 
    socket.emit('message', formatMessage(botName, `Welcome to the WPRBXmas Listener Chat, ${user.username}!`));

    // Broadcast when a user connects
    socket.broadcast
        .to(user.room)
        .emit('message', formatMessage(botName, `${user.username} has entered the chat, bearing tidings of comfort & oi.`));
   
    // Send users and room info.
    io.to(user.room).emit('roomUsers', {
        room: user.room,
        users: getRoomUsers(user.room)
    });

    });
   
    // Listen for chatMessage
    socket.on('chatMessage', (msg) => {
        const user = getCurrentUser(socket.id);

    io.to(user.room).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, msg));
    });

       // Broadcast when a user disconnects 
       socket.on('disconnect', () => {
           const user = userLeave(socket.id);

           if(user) {
            io.to(user.room).emit('message', formatMessage(botName, `${user.username} has left the chat for a long winter's nap.`)
            );

       // Send users and room info.
    io.to(user.room).emit('roomUsers', {
        room: user.room,
        users: getRoomUsers(user.room)
    });
           }
    });


});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

**Here's my users.js file**:

```
const users = [];

// Join user to chat
function userJoin(id, username, room) {
    const user = { id, username, room};

    users.push(user);

    return user;

}

// Get current user 
function getCurrentUser (id) {
    return users.find(user => user.id === id);
}

// User leaves chat
function userLeave(id) {
    const index = users.findIndex(user => user.id === id);

    if(index !== -1) {
        return users.splice(index, 1)[0];

    }
}

// Get room users
function getRoomUsers (room) {
    return users.filter(user => user.room === room);
}

module.exports = {
    userJoin,
    getCurrentUser,
    userLeave,
    getRoomUsers

};
```

**And here's my messages.js file:**

```
const moment = require('moment');

function formatMessage(username, text) {
    return {
        username,
        text,
        time: moment().format('h:mm a')
    };
}

module.exports = formatMessage;
```

I realize this is a lot but I'm guessing someone with whose more familiar with Socket.io will be able to take on look at this and see the problem immediately.

Many thanks to anyone taking the time to read and respond!  Happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

I've actually just built a socket.io chat yestarday,deployed it on heroku,something'
s wrong with heroku servers.If your app managed to work on heroku,and crashed after some time because of the traffic you can use "heroku restart" in the app folder,that worked for me,you could try to host it somewhere else.Merry Christmas!